# How to add elements to a vector of tuples

Tags: c++

I just have this:

```
std::vector<int[2]> ints;
```

how can I add elements to this vector?

using either `ints.insert()` or `ints.push_back()`?

No idea how to do this, C/C++ newb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure vector<int[2]> is the same as vector<int*> ... so push_back(&some_int) ? If you are looking for pairs, you should use std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > ints;

Comment: `std::vector<int[2]> ints;` wont even compile on some compilers, what was your goal?

Comment: `int[2]` is not valid because arrays are not copyable or moveable

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int,2>>`

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon No, it is not. There is no decay of types inside template arguments. However, `vector<int[2]>` is illegal because `std::allocator::destroy` is ill-formed for arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way you can achieve the functionality you are looking for:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> ints;
```

Then you would add a tuple to the vector like this:

```
ints.push_back(std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```

Edit/Update:
if you were looping over you vector and `i` is your integer index used during the loop, then to access to tuple you can do this:

```
int intOne, intTwo;

intOne = std::get<0>(ints[i]);
intTwo = std::get<1>(ints[i]);
```

here is some more info on [get for a tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/get/)

Comment: thanks, can you demonstrate how to access the tuple (I can access the vector at an element, but not sure how to access tuple

Comment: @Olegzandr info on accessing the tuple has been added.

Comment: that is mucho bueno grassias

Comment: @Olegzandr de nada... if this helped and answered you question please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, that's why I didn't accept, but I did upvote

Answer (score 12):

With C++ 11:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(0, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract tuple using std::get

Here is the C++ 11 link with example:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get

The full article about tuples is here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple